# like and send options for a website

Tags: html, facebook-social-plugins

I may not be looking in the correct place, but I am trying to add a LIKE and SEND option on my business website.  My website is written using html 4.  The only info I found on FB for these options is written for html 5 or xfbml or iframe.  I copied the code and pasted it to my website as instructed, but it does not show the boxes or seem to work correctly.  Does anyone know if I can use these options with html 4?

Comment: yes you can... Are you getting any sort of error?  It would also help to post the code that you are using.

Comment: This is the Facebook approved way to create Like/Send buttons: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Answer (score 2):

Below is solution for your problem step by step :) 
As I guess your code is not working because you not use javascript properly

**You can solve your problem in 5 Steps**

**Step 1**

Create a new facebook app using the [link](https://developers.facebook.com/apps) and note its **App ID/API Key**

**Step 2**

use your App ID/API Key which you note in **Step 1**

The following code will load and initialize the JavaScript SDK with all common options. Replace **YOUR_APP_ID** and **WWW.YOUR_DOMAIN.COM** with the appropriate values. The best place to put this code is right after the opening `<body>` tag.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
FB.init({
  appId      : 'YOUR_APP_ID', // App ID
  channelUrl : '//WWW.YOUR_DOMAIN.COM/channel.html', // Channel File
  status     : true, // check login status
  cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
  xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
});

// Additional initialization code here
  };

  // Load the SDK Asynchronously
  (function(d){
 var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
 js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
 js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
 d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
   }(document));
</script>
```

**Step 3**

Create a channel.html file with the below code

```
  <?php
    $cache_expire = 60*60*24*365;
    header("Pragma: public");
    header("Cache-Control: max-age=".$cache_expire);
    header('Expires: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', time()+$cache_expire) . ' GMT');
  ?>
  <script src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
```

**Step 4**
Add an XML namespace to the `<html>` tag of your document. This is necessary for XFBML to work in earlier versions of Internet Explorer.

```
<html xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
```

**Step 5** 
Place the code for your plugin wherever you want the plugin to appear on your page and don't forget to replace **WWW.YOUR_DOMAIN.COM** with your domain name

```
<fb:like href="WWW.YOUR_DOMAIN.COM" send="true" width="450" show_faces="true"></fb:like>
```

**You can read all the above in details where the almost all information is get below is the links**

1. [here you can get like plugin and other details](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/)
2. [here you can get javascript, channel file details and other details](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/)

Comment: Thanks for vote up 
I want to known who is this please
because when you do lots of effort and some like this is a nice reward of your effort 
thanks again

Comment: **Great answer!**  You used *almost* every formatting tool :) [links](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/a/9151296/558021), **bold**, `code blocks`, lists... Throw in some italics and block quotes next time too! (If the need arises ;)  I like formatting. It makes the post easier to read by outlining important statements and shows that the poster made an effort.  Remember - there is a reason that the voting mechanism is anonymous.  I believe that even the diamond mods can't (under normal circumstances) see who *exactly* voted on a specific post.

Answer (score 1):

As evanmcd said, but with a plus+:

You don't have to know HTML5 or XFBML (IFRAME is still not supported). Just copy the code from here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/ and use it. XFBML is supported in all browsers (actually, it doesn't have to be supported, it's a part of facebook (xFaceBookml). I hope it helps... remember that you don't have to know it.